# add body {username:"bb",password"xx"} in request HTTP in $.ajax{()}

Tags: jquery

I want to send a request http with $.ajax{()}
but I have a probleme of HTTP400
HTTP400:INCORRECT QUERY. The server was unable to process the request because the syntax is not valid.

the data I have are :

```
headers : Content-Type  = application/json
body :{
   "UserName": "trinita",
   "Password": "112A" }
```

my request http is:

```
jQuery.ajax({
 url: data.npsod.conn.server+'Account/Login',
 method: 'POST',
 contentType: 'application/json',
 dataType : "json",
 data:{UserName:"trinita",Password:"112A"},  
 xhrFields: {
 withCredentials: false
 },
 error: function(){
 alert('failure');
                }

})
```

I do not understand why I have this error ,I know that normally it comes from data :{UserName…….} but I have note another solution

HTTP400:INCORRECT QUERY. The server was unable to process the request because the syntax is not valid.
thank you  :) !

Comment: `JSON.stringify(...)` your data.

Comment: you want to say : I replace with data:JSON.stringify({UserName:"trinita",Password:"112A"}),   ?

Comment: Yes, stringify the object you are trying to give to the ajax call

Comment: I add but I have the same problem